# How to invoke a variable of another class.

Tags: class, variables, methods, call, invoke

I have a problem at calling a variable of another class.Lets say we have class1 and class2    and class2 has a method like :

```
public Class2{

public void method2 (Element ele, Grammar utterance, String user) {

String speech =................ 

         }
   }
```

And my purpose is getting this "speech" variable and passing it to class1. Any ideas about how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Declare before method: public static String speech
-Initialize in method or out: speech="hi"
-Call from the other class (static scope): Class1.speech

Comment: but the problem is i m not allowed to change anything(for exp. from void to public or as you did making it static) at the current code i can only add sth.Because when i change sth then so many codes get effected of this and i need a solution which does not modify the code but only adds some lines of codes!!! And this String speech is defined inside a method of class2 so it is a local variable and i dont know how to reach it...

Comment: btw, when i do it as u said then it works perfectly,thanks a lot but i m not sure if i have been asked to find the result with some modifications on the code!!!

Comment: Also you could return speech value (String) instead of void or pass speech as method parameter

Answer (score 0):

You could change void method2(...) to public String method2(...) and return speech. Then in your first class you have an instance of class2 and calling class2.method2(...) will give the class 1 the speech variable

Comment: but the problem is i m not allowed to change anything(like from void to public) at the current code i can only add sth.Because when i change sth then so many codes get effected of this and i need a solution which does not modify the code but only adds some lines of codes!!!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to have an instance of Class2 in your other Class1 so example would be:

```
Class1 mySpeech = new Class1();
```

Now the object that has access to `mySpeech` can access the string variable contained as speech is a public variable.

```
mySpeech.speech
```

But it is good practice to create getter/setter methods for this which can be created using the eclipse shortcut:

```
Sources->Generate Getters and Setters
```

Also when naming a class use capital for the first letter and invoke the camel casing convention.So when your naming a class call it `Class1` or `ClassOne`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have some kind of public visibility in the object giving the string. Then either pass the string from the first object into the second, or pass the object by reference into the second object (less recommended).

```
public FirstClass {
    private String speech = "I am the first object!";

    public String getSpeech() {
        return speech;
    }
}

public SecondClass {
    private string speechCopy;

    public void takeSpeech(string speechCopy) {
        this.speechCopy = speechCopy + " (not really, I'm a copy!)";
    }
}
```

From here, you just have to call the methods to invoke the behavior you want. You can leave the code as it is, but add the get/set methods to each object so that they can be passed variables and references.

Comment: but the problem is i m not allowed to change anything(for exp. from void to public or as you did to private) at the current code i can only add sth.Because when i change sth then so many codes get effected of this and i need a solution which does not modify the code but only adds some lines of codes!!! And  this String speech is defined inside a method of class2 so it is a local variable and i dont know how to reach it...

Comment: The solution I provided was general. Given the code you provided, you can still add a method to the object that returns the value of string without adding anything to the existing code.

For your example, add the getSpeech() method to your class 2 and just have 'return speech;' inside the method.